# mysql ignore index for order by on join

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

```
CREATE TABLE `call_session` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `continue_reason_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `continue_by` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_reason_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `call_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `answered_call_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_call_session_contact_id` (`contact_id`),
  KEY `ix_call_session_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `ix_call_session_campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
  KEY `call_session_continue_by_foreign` (`continue_by`),
  KEY `call_session_end_reason_id_foreign` (`end_reason_id`),
  KEY `ix_call_session_end_time` (`end_time`),
  KEY `ix_call_session_start_time` (`start_time`),
  KEY `ix_call_session_continue_reason_id` (`continue_reason_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `call_session_campaign_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_id`) REFERENCES `campaign` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `call_session_continue_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`continue_by`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `call_session_continue_reason_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`continue_reason_id`) REFERENCES `continue_reason` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `call_session_end_reason_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`end_reason_id`) REFERENCES `end_reason` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `call_session_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE `continue_reason` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_continue_reason_project_id` (`project_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `continue_reason_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

- The `call_session` table contain more than 500,000 rows.
- The `continue_reason` table contain only one row.

When I join the `continue_reason` table for the `name` column, mysql ignore the `start_date` index so the query takes between 1.8 to 3 seconds.
I can't figure out why.

**The problematic query is:**

```
SELECT `call_session`.`id`,
       `continue_reason`.`name`
FROM `call_session`
LEFT JOIN `continue_reason` ON `continue_reason`.`id` = `call_session`.`continue_reason_id`
ORDER  BY `call_session`.`start_time` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

*Explain result:*
[image: Explain results with join]

**Same query without join** works great:

```
SELECT `call_session`.`id`,
       (SELECT `name` FROM `continue_reason` WHERE id = `call_session`.`continue_reason_id`) AS `continue_reason.name`
FROM `call_session`
ORDER  BY `call_session`.`start_time` DESC LIMIT  1;
```

*Explain results:*
[image: Explain results without join]

I found many similar questions but I don't have any DISTINCT, no GROUP BY, and there is a very clear benefit for using the index.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

P.S. Force index didn't help.

Here is the [Optimizer report](https://pastebin.com/sByidtF8)

Comment: I would suggest you get rid of all the call_session indexes, and instead create a new one on 
  (`continue_reason_id`,`start_time`)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Elaborate? That's the whole thing! Also, while these queries *could* produce the same result, they are NOT the 'same query'!

Comment: This query is not the full production query. The full query use more joins, I narrow it for the first join I found that cause this issue.
Can you explain why do you think it will solve my issue?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, looks a bit better, but still 1.6 seconds is not acceptable. The explain now looks like some index being used but still use filesort: https://imgur.com/aSEiz4X

Comment: 1.6 seconds for 1.2m rows seems ok to me.

Comment: Not ok at all, you can see the second query, it takes 0.015 even though it makes the same operation as the first one.
If the index is being used to sort start_date - the response should not take more than that.

Comment: But the second query is an inner join or, rather, a corellated subquery

Comment: If I remove the join, and make a simple select with order by start_date and limit 1 I'm getting answer in no time. It means that the index is working well. I don't see any reason the left join should make the query take so much time. There is no point in running over the table when I ask for 1 line with order by indexed column.

Comment: I seem to remember that the EXPLAINEXTENDED site has an article on 'late row lookups' in MySQL, which might be relevant

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for the original query after adding the composite index.

Comment: Is `LIMIT 1` in the real query?  Taking "no time" could be a red herring.

Comment: Drop KEY `ix_call_session_continue_reason_id` (`continue_reason_id`) -- The Optimizer does not (or should not, in this case) use indexes when most of the table matches.  Dropping it would eliminate a poor option for the Optimizer.

Comment: Which version of MySQL is this?

Comment: @oysteing mysql 5.7

Comment: Not sure what is happening here.  If you can you provide the optimizer trace for the query, I should be able to see what is going on.  See https://oysteing.blogspot.no/2016/01/how-to-get-optimizer-trace-for-query.html for advice on how to get the optimizer trace.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help! Sorry for the late reply, here is the full optimizer report https://pastebin.com/sByidtF8.